# Equal (not a token) in an ANTLR grammar. What does this mean?

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, token, equals

What does the construct `basename =` in the following rule?

```
tabname:
   (ID'.')? basename = ID
;
```

There is this single occurrence of `basename` in the grammar.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using equals in that syntax creates a variable called `basename` that can then be referenced in actions:

```
tabname:
    (ID '.')? basename=ID {
        if ($basename.equals("CAT"))
            System.out.println("CAT found");
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

It is used to name variables.

This can be very useful if  you want to run some code during  the parser.

Consider the java calculator example:

```
expr returns [float r]
{
float a,b;
r=0;
}
:   #(PLUS a=expr b=expr)   {r = a+b;}
|   #(STAR a=expr b=expr)   {r = a*b;}
|   i:INT           {r = (float)Integer.parseInt(i.getText());}
;
```

Here we say when we match a tree that has a PLUS or STAR token followed by 2 expressions, we'll match the expressions and name them `a` and `b` respectively.

After we'll use those variables we matched in a java statement.  This statement is contained inside the `{` and `}` brackets.  Here we use the java statements to actually do the calculation.